# Find Bookmarks in Footer using OpenXML

Tags: openxml

If I run this code:

```
        For Each bookmarkStart As DW.BookmarkStart In Doc.RootPart.RootElement.Descendants(Of DW.BookmarkStart)()
            Debug.WriteLine(bookmarkStart.Name)
        Next
```

I will get output for all bookmarks EXCEPT for those in the document footer. Do you know how to get the bookmarks in the footer? Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following:

```
For Each Book_Mark As BookmarkStart In Doc.MainDocumentPart.FooterParts
Debug.WriteLine(bookmarkStart.Name)
Next
```